# clean string removing a list of values

Tags: php

i was writing this code to remove a list of values from a dynamic string key

```
//key
$chiave = "motore a scoppio di seconda generazione";
//sanitize string
//$chiave = pulisci($chiave);
//clean from double whitespaces
$chiave = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$chiave);
//convert in lowercase
$chiave = strtolower($chiave);
//define array with all values to remove
$togliere = array("a","il","lo","la","egli","gli","li","di","do","e","è","alla","alle","&","un","uno","una");
$togliere2 = array("d'","l'");
//explode words
$keyval = explode(" ",$chiave);
//remove values
$keyvalclean = array_values(array_diff($keyval, $togliere));
//remove others values
$valori = array();
for($x=0; $x<=count($keyvalclean); $x++){
    $valori[] = str_replace($togliere2,"",$keyvalclean[$x]);
}
//print the result
echo implode(" ",$valori);
```

this will output "motore scoppio seconda generazione"

there is a faster and optimized code to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay to me. But you don't need to loop through the array to remove the values using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace). This function can take an array as its argument and perform the replacement on each one of them **in one go**.

This:

```
$valori = array();
for($x=0; $x<=count($keyvalclean); $x++){
    $valori[] = str_replace($togliere2,"",$keyvalclean[$x]);
}
```

can be changed to just:

```
$valori = str_replace($togliere2, "", $keyvalclean);
echo implode(" ",$valori);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/124396)

Comment: thanks for the trick. wich other cleaning you would make on the text string to perform a good search query?

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

You could insert an array to replaced by `""` with this function.